# Асинхронная функция в цикле

Tags: ios, swift, асинхронность

Необходимо сделать выборку всех пользователей в базе данных (использую Firestore), записать в массив и этот массив в качестве результата передать в основной код. При всём этом у пользователя может быть аватарка, которая хранится в  Firebase storage и её тоже надо подтянуть оттуда. 
Сделал следующее:

```
static func downloadAllUsers(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
    let userStore = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
    //Тут подписываюсь на изменения в базе
    userStore.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let documents = documentSnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            //Объявил пустой массив для дальнейшего использования
            var users: [User] = [User]()
            for doc in documents {
                let id = doc.documentID
//Исключаю текущего пользователя
                if id != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    let data = doc.data()

                    let name = data["name"] as! String
                    let email = data["email"] as! String
                    let chatIds = data["chatIds"] as! [String]
                    //let pictureUrl = data["profilePic"] as! String

                    let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child("usersProfilePics")
                    let pathImg = storage.child(id)
                    // Запрос на получение картинки из storage
                    pathImg.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in

                        if error == nil {
//Если есть картинка
                            guard let data = data else {
                                print("Error NO DATA")
                                return
                            }
                            guard let profilePic = UIImage(data: data) else {
                                print("Error dowload image")
                                return
                            }
                            let user = User(id: id, name: name, email: email, chatIds: chatIds, profilePic: profilePic)

                            users.append(user)
                        } else {
//Нету картинки
                            guard let defaultPicture = UIImage(named: "profile pic") else {return}

                            let user = User(id: id, name: name, email: email, chatIds: chatIds, profilePic: defaultPicture)

                            users.append(user)
                            //print("Error getData: ", error!.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        // Вот этот кусок меня смущает
                        if users.count == documents.count - 1 {
                            print("USERS: ", users)
                            completion(users)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }


        } else {
            print("Error downloadAllUsers: ", error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Как грамотно мне передать сформированный массив с картинками в основной код?

```
if users.count == documents.count - 1 {
                            print("USERS: ", users)
                            completion(users)
                        }
```

Это смахивает на не очень грамотный подход, на мой взгляд, хоть и работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `DispatchGroup`:

```
var results = [User]()
// создаем группу задач
let group = DispatchGroup()
items.forEach {
// добавляем в группу новую задачу с помощью enter()
    group.enter()
    if $0.haveAvatar {
        downloadAvatarWithCompletion {
// завершаем задачу после загрузки аватара с помощью leave()
results.append($0)
           group.leave()
        }
    } else {
// обязательно нужно, чтобы количество enter() == leave()
results.append($0)
        group.leave()
    }
}

// этот блок отработает на указанной DispatchQueue когда все таски завершатся
group.notify(DispatchQueue(label: "someQueue.myapp.com")) {
// лучше отсортировать результаты после асинхронного добавления
   results.sort { $0.id < $1.id }
      print("DONE WITH \(results)")
}
```

еще, асинхронный код всегда можно "распрямить" при помощи `DispatchSemaphore`:

```
items.forEach {
// создаем семафор
   let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
   doAsyncTaskForItem($0, withCompletion: {
// подаем сигнал когда все асинхронные дела для текущего объекта закончились
       semaphore.signal()
   })
// ждем сигнала
   _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
}
```

такой код уже должен выполняться в бакграундном потоке и это будет заметно медленнее, чем в случае с `DispatchGroup`, но следует помнить, что и так можно делать, иногда помогает